# How to disable generation of dump.txt by proguard when building android gradle project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I have an android project build with gradle.

It is obfuscated with proguard.

Proguard generates dump.txt file that has 70 MB.

I don't want it. I don't need it. It exausts my SSD.

Hou can I disable dump.txt file generation?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following locations for the -dump flag.

- proguard-android.txt
- proguard-rules.pro
- project.properties (proguard include property)

If you find argument '-dump dump.txt', simply delete it.

Since you know the name of the output file, you can grep your project directory to find out where this is defined.

Comment: That didn't help. I was unable to locate -dump anywhere in files: proguard-android.txt, proguard-rules.txt, local.properties. I was unable to locate in anywhere in project files

Comment: I found it in android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml, but commenting it there does not seem to have an effect :-(